# How do I grep a Puppet manifest File object to find if an attribute exists?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I want to find all the manifests in all my modules that use the File object and don't have the "owner" attribute.

For example, I have this File object:

```
file { '/etc/mydir':
  source  => 'puppet:///modules/mymodule/mydir_settings',
  ensure  => 'directory',
  recurse => true
}
```

And it's missing the "owner" attribute. I want to be able to grep this manifest and find this file object that has a missing "owner" attribute.

The best grep I was able to come up with (from searching the web) is this:

```
grep -Pzo -e "file\s+{[^}]*}" ./manifests/init.pp
```

But it has these flaws:

1) It doesn't "highlight" those objects with the missing "owner" attribute.
 2) It fails to show file objects that have a variable with curly brackets around it like:

```
 file { "/etc/myotherdir/${var1}":
```

3) It fails to ignore file objects that have been commented out (which isn't a bad thing, but it just doesn't handle know how to handle them)

I would like to be able to get an output of all (and only) the file objects that have a missing "owner" attribute.

Comment: Show sample input that does and does not have the "owner attribute" (whatever that is!) and the expected output given that input. You say `It fails to ignore file objects that have been commented out` - include those in your sample input/output too. Don't expect the people reading this to have any idea what "a Puppet manifest file object" is - simply post truly representative sample input and expected output so we don't have to become "Puppet manifest" experts to help you and instead your question is simply "I have this text as input and want this other text as output".

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this might be what you're looking for but without more truly representative sample input/output it's a guess:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^file[[:space:]]+{/ { inFileObj = 1 }

inFileObj {
    rec = rec $0 ORS

    if ( /^[[:space:]]*owner[[:space:]]*=>/ ) {
        gotOwner = 1
    }

    if ( /^}$/ ) {
        if ( ! gotOwner ) {
            printf "%s", rec
        }
        inFileObj = gotOwner = 0
        rec = ""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
file { '/etc/mydir':
  source  => 'puppet:///modules/mymodule/mydir_settings',
  ensure  => 'directory',
  recurse => true
}
```